# Changing points on map to make it filled choropleth map

Tags: qgis

I am trying to convert my points on this map so each point is shaded into the area it is so I am essentially creating a filled choropleth map with the data used currently I managed to differentiate the points as red for negative and green for positive using a graduate symbology for the map as can be seen on the image below.

I have tried different methods in order to do this but I am stumped as I have watched different videos and followed guides online but nothing works. I am also working my way through the tutorials but they don't offer clear guidance on it.

[image: Picture of the map I am currently creating - in a bit more detail I am simply wanting to create the points to filled for each area it is in representing each value that is in the area so I want the map to essentially look like green for positive scores and red for negative scores]

Comment: Do your points have an attribute column that relates to an attribute column of the polygons? This could be an identifier code or a name (although matching on names can sometimes fail because spelling or capitalisation etc). If so then you make a Join from the area data to the points. Is that one thing you already tried?

Comment: hi yes i have tried this as well

Comment: The "join" should work, so without some more detail on your data I don't see how we can help much more. Can you put your data somewhere we can get it (eg public share on Dropbox or similar) or tell us where to get it or show more information about your data, specifically the columns in the attributes for both points and areas?